# Trigger a github workflow before running another workflow on : release [created]

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions, github-release

When I create a new release on Github via its UI, I want to trigger the release.yml workflow.

Within the release.yml workflow, I'd like to first run the ci.yml  workflow and only if it passes, go ahead and create a release. If the ci.yml worflow fails, remove the newly created release on the Github UI as well.

I have 2 YAML files ci.yml and release.yml

In my release.yml file

```yaml
on:  
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  # I want to run the ci.yml workflow here and then run the jobs below if it passes.
  # If the ci.yml workflow fails, revert back and remove the created release.


  job1:
    .........


  job2:
    .........
```

If there is a better way to do achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: You could use the `workflow_run` trigger on the `release.yml` file when the `ci.yml` workflow is completed [(example)](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/12-run-workflow.yml). Then you can use the `if conditional` with `github.event.workflow_run.conclusion` to perform what you want depending on the `ci.yml` workflow result.

Comment: @GuiFalourd, that would mean my release.yml file would be triggered on every ci.yml workflow run and when release is created. The purpose of release.yml file is to run once in a while when I create a new release. And before a new release I want to ensure ci.yml workflow passes.

Comment: In thay case, you can trigger the release.yml file when a new release tag is created: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) event with a condition.

For example, in `release.yaml`, you can add something like this to run a step only if `ci` workflow has successfully completed:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ci]
    types: [completed]

jobs:
  on-success:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'This is where your release steps can continue'
  on-failure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'you can remove this or do something with it like sending an email about why you are not releasing'
```

There are few other ways to trigger a workflow from another workflow. Some are here:

1. [Using Workflow Dispatch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch)
2. [Repository Dispatch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/repository-dispatch)

In your case, if you prefer to use `Workflow Dispatch`, you can simply invoke the `release` workflow as last step of `ci` workflow which will satisfy your needs of running `release` workflow only when ci is successful.

If you prefer `Repository Dispatch`, you can dispatch the event at the last step of `ci` workflow. In this approach you can pass additional inputs to `release` workflow so that you can have additional flexibility in `release` workflow.

There are many other way to trigger a workflow which are well documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows). Few of the ways you can consider are: creating a tag in your `ci` workflow and then use that event in `release` workflow.